Getting Issue "unsafe implementation of TrustManager" By Google play store
i am working on an app having APIs for data getting and transmitting so due to security reasons i had to use the "TrustManager" in, TrustManager Class I implemented Hostname verifier and that's it .i did not implemented any thing else because i do not have much knowledge of how to implement properly .now i recevied mail from google play store that i have issue in app of "unsafe implementation of TrustManager"
Here Is My TrustManager.java class code


public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {


    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return _AcceptedIssuers;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {
                if (hostname.equals("MyHostname.in")) {

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }


            }

        });

        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
        }

        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ignored) {



        }

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }

}

If any one have knowledge of this then please help me and suggest me proper code and any other method of implementation of this

Remove that HttpsTrustManager from your code, and please never consider doing something like that again. I do not know what problem you are trying to solve, but saying that you want to turn off security is not going to viewed as a good solution.

Instead of using a custom Trust manager and Hostname verifier you should simply deploy a correct HTTPS certificate to your server, then you don't need to using insecure code like what you have posted here. Thanks to Google that they have stopped you before your app endangers the users of your app.

i have correct HTTPS certificate at server but when i do  not use TrustManager.allowallssl() then app do not get data in response it only display Error Message Of onErrorResponse.so tell me what should i do ?
